# Design MapReduce function in Hadoop Streaming

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

I am using Hadoop Streaming (ver 2.9.0) with Python. The input of my MapReduce is a text file. My `<key,value>` pairs are as following, where `key` are numeric, and `value` are sets of numeric):

```
 k1,v11
 k2,v21
 k1,v12
 k2,v22
 k1,v13
 k2,v23
```

I want to output (where `v11 union v12` represents union between sets `v11` and `v12`):

```
k1, v11 union v12, v11 union v13, v12 union v13 
k2, v21 union v22, v21 union v23, v22 union v23
```

......

So, I implement Map.py:

```
for line in sys.stdin:
  key, values = line.strip().split(",")
  print(key,values)
```

And my Reduce.py is

```
for line in sys.stdin:
  key, values = line.strip().split(",")
  if key==current_key:
     # save values to a temporary list
     list.append(values)
     print(key,values)
  # when moving to another attribute
  else:
     for l in list:
       # we process union between elements of list her, save it to aggre variable
       aggre=....
     print(current_key, aggre)
     #clear the list
     list[:]=[]
     #set new key as current_key
     current_key=key
     #save values to this list
     list.append(values)
```

The output of my Map.py is same as its input. In Reducer.py, since Hadoop streaming reads line by line, I wait until I read all lines which have the same key before start calculation. Then, I calculate right after changing to other keys.

However, I feel like that this implementation is similar as sequential method, i.e., nothing is parallel here. Please correct me if I am wrong?

If it is really sequential, is there any way of design MapReduce to make it really parallel. For example, I want Reducer.py should be like this:

```
for line in sys.stdin:
  key, values = line.strip().split(",")
  # save values to a temporary list
  list.append(values)
for l in list:
  # we process union between elements of list her, save it to aggre variable
  aggre=....
print(key, aggre)
```

When I use this code, together with set `mapred.reduce.tasks=n`, the result is split into `n` files, each files contains only 1 `<key,value>` as I expected. 
However, I got error when set `n` too high.

My key `k1,k2,..` represents attributes in database. I want to compute union of values on each attribute, and computing on each attribute `k1,k2,..` is done in parallel. If there are 5 attributes, there should be 5 Reducers. And so on.

However, I got error if always set `mapred.reduce.tasks= number of attributes`. For example, if when number of attributes is 30, if I set `mapred.reduce.tasks= 30`, there will be Java exception errors.

So, my question is:
How to ensure that each key (or each attribute) is processed only by 1 reducer even when I set `n < number of attributes`.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Thanks for your edit. I have edited my questions to make it clearer.

Comment: Okay, well, if you have 5 keys, there should be 5 reducers. Are you not seeing that in the YARN UI?

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that when keys are big, e.g., 20. If I tried to set 20 reducers, there will be exception error. I have to set no. of reducers low enough. However, how can I ensure that pairs with same key are processed by 1 reducer?

Comment: Any elements with the same key are always processed by the same reducer. That's how mapreduce works. Edit your question to include any error stacktrace and add the data that caused it. If you are interested in using Python, there are other libraries to process such data like MrJob or PySpark. Otherwise, see this post on how you can test your code locally before using Hadoop http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/writing-an-hadoop-mapreduce-program-in-python/

Comment: Sorry for my late. I know that any elements with the same key are always processed by the same reducer. But I am sure is this still true if no. of reducers < k. E.g., Suppose I have k distinct keys, and when I set no. of reducers < k, the above still be true?

Comment: That property is defined as the "default number of reduce tasks per job". It's not an upper limit, and I personally haven't seen setting it high cause any exceptions that I remember

Comment: So, you mean we can set number of reduce tasks as high as we want? I do not count the speed, I just want to confirm if the MapReduce should run normally with any no. of reducers we set?

Comment: Well, I mean, you'll hit out of memory exceptions. Might want to read https://github.com/paulhoule/infovore/wiki/Choosing-the-number-of-reducers